# Can't open extension in Safari Extension Builder

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I want to build on an open source Safari extension using Safari 7 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

I've downloaded the .safariextz file, but the file is greyed out when selecting Add Extension after clicking the little `+` button in the lower-left corner:

[Can't open an extension in Safari http://filedump.fredsted.me/fmm79.png](http://filedump.fredsted.me/fmm79.png)

Shouldn't I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.safariextz` file is an already packaged extension. You need to extract it back to its unpackaged state before adding it to the Extension Builder. You can do this with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
xar -xf 'whatever.safariextz'
```

A folder named `whatever.safariextension` should appear which you can then add in the Safari Extension Builder.

**Edit**: I just realised that the source of the extension you are working with is available: https://github.com/zanmato/Add-to-Transmission - You would be better off cloning the Git repository directly and then modifying that, rather than extracting the source from the packaged file.